# How to update a view without waiting for another operation to finish

Tags: c#

lets say I have a GroupBox with several Labels. In these Labels, various IP-related information are displayed. One info is the external IP address of the machine.

```
string externalIP = "";

try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");
    request.Timeout = 3000;
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.WebResponse> response =  request.GetResponseAsync();

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.Result.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        if (response.Result.ContentLength != -1)
        {
             externalIP = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }               
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    externalIP = "Error.";
}

if (externalIP == "")
{
    return "No service.";
}
else
{
    return externalIP = (new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")).Matches(externalIP)[0].ToString();
}
```

This method is called from following code:

```
private void updateNetworkIP()
{ 
    string ip4e = "External IPv4: " + getExternalIPv4();
    lblIP4external.Text = ip4e;

    //Get some more info here.
}
```

How do I execute the code after getExternalIPv4() even when it's not finished yet? It works when setting a TimeOut like I did above but sometimes the request just takes a little longer but still completes successfully. So I want to still be able to display the external IP but continue to execute the other methods for refreshing the GroupBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BackgroundWorker` will deliver what you are after. Sample code:

```
BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getExternalIPv4Back);
bg.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(writeLabel);
bg.RunWorkerAsync();
//The code below this point will be executed while the BackgroundWorker does its work
```

You have to define `getExternalIPv4Back` as a `DoWork Event Method` and include inside it the code to be executed in parallel; also `writeLabel` as a `RunWorkerCompleted Event`(required to edit the label without provoking muti-threading-related errors). That is:

```
private void getExternalIPv4Back(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    IP = "External IPv4: " + getExternalIPv4(); //IP -> Globally defined variable
}

private void writeLabel(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   lblIP4external.Text = IP;
}
```